# How to know if another user is editing a cell in current sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am doing a real time pending orders list and I am required to sort (DESC) **date** column whenever it is being edited (in order not miss all the latest orders).

However if 2nd user is editing a cell and during that moment script auto-sorts the table when 1st user changes **date** field - Google Spreadsheet does not move the pointer of the 2nd user to a new location, thus he ends up writing on the wrong cell.

Is there a way to programmatically know if another user is editing any cell on the sheet (then delay the auto-sort function) or automatically correct the cursor position of the user?

Comment: Original v copy: Just a thought, copy it to a new sheet and sort the contents of the new sheet.

Comment: Not exactly a workout, you can use the chat feature in Google Docs and communicate regarding stopping works and continuing it....

Comment: In the mean time I'll probably go with eddyparkinson suggestion.
I'll make one sheet - sorted viet - for big screen in the workplace.
But the working one will be sorted when it would not interrupt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to tell that they are editing. You could use a onEdit trigger to tell when the cells change.

Comment: onEdit triggers after the cell has been edited, not when cell IS BEING edited

Comment: Yes thats why I said that theres no way to tell.